# Is a monomial basis a Groebner basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

Given a monomial ideal

$$I = \langle x^{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in A \subset \Bbb Z^n_{\geq 0}\rangle,$$

I want to know if the rest of the polynomial division of $f \in \mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ by the monomial basis of $I$ is unique. In particular, is a monomial basis (eventually a reduced one) a Groebner basis? By going through examples, it seems that the rest of such a division is unique, but I would like to have a proof. Can somebody provide an explanation, a reference or a solution proposal? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to ask whether, given a set of monomials $S$, the Groebner basis of $\langle S\rangle$ also consists of monomials. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks. I realized given some examples, that for f a polynomial, it's division with a monomial basis provides a rest which remains unchanged upon permutation of the elements of the monomial basis following the polynomial division. That made me think if by chance any monomial basis of a given ideal is a groebner basis. That's my question.

Comment: What about $\langle x,x^2\rangle$? If you reduce it to get rid of things like this then the end result consists of independent elements, so Groebner reduction shouldn't change things.

Comment: From Wikipedia: $G$ is a Groebner basis for $I$ if "the ideal generated by the leading monomials of the polynomials in $I$ equals the ideal generated by the leading monomials of $G$".

Comment: I need to check that. I thus assume that my assumption is wrong. How about the question that you suggested, i.e. given a monomial basis S of an ideal I, can it be completed into a Groebner basis G, such that G consists of monomials only?

Comment: So, how can I understand your example following the definition, which is, how can I prove that $<x>$ is not a Groebner basis?

Comment: Take the minimal elements $A'$ in $A$, so those that cannot be obtained from any other by increasing co-ordinates (and *not* decreasing any). The corresponding monomials are your Groebner basis.

Comment: But then you are rather reducing and not completing it, which is you are not extending it. It then seems as if the I tial basis was a Groebner basis. Now I am totally confused.

Comment: Extending the basis would result in a different ideal, in general, unless you add redundant generators. No element of a Groebner basis is redundant.

Comment: Well, if you apply Buchberger's algorithm to a set of monomials, then the "cross terms" you generate will always end up being zero, so that says you don't need to add anything to get to a Groebner basis.

Comment: In other word, Buchberger's criterion is easy to verify for a set of monomials; therefore, a set of monomials always forms a Groebner basis.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler. Thanks. Given that a monomial basis is a Groebner basis and that the Buchberger's algorithm or a similar one can be expensive in finding a Groebner basis for a given ideal $I = (f_1,...,f_n),$ where the basis $S=\{f_1,...f_n\}$ may contain polynomials, is it possible to find a monomial basis $S'$ such that $I'=(S') $ and $I=I'$? In that case we already get a Groebner basis given that a monomial basis is a Groebner basis. I guess, by including all monomials of all polynomials in $S$ into $S'$ we may get a monomial basis. I hope for a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @user996159: You want $I = I' = (S')$, but there are ideals that don't have a monomial basis, for example $I = (x+1) \subset k[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

A (possible infinite) collection of monomials generating an ideal $I$ is a Gröbner basis (commutative, non-commutative, or in more general settings for other algebraic structures). To see it, notice that if two monomials overlap, then they reduce to zero no matter which one you choose to rewrite, so the conditions of the *Diamond Lemma* are satisfied.